# Unable to build HERE SDK Premium for ios-arm64-simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, here-api, heremaps-ios-sdk

Having trouble building HERE SDK for iOS (Premium 3.19) for an ios-arm64-simulator. The error produced by Xcode 13 on an M1 pro processor is:

```
ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking in dylib built for iOS, file 'Pods/HEREMaps/framework/NMAKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/NMAKit.framework/NMAKit'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

After some research and testing it looks like HERE SDK's XCFramework folder as well as the Cocoapod configuration only include `ios-arm64` and `ios-x86_64-simulator`. It looks like the podspec is attempting to fix this by overriding the target app's iOS simulator excluded architectures (adding excluded architecture "arm64"). This likely works fine in cases where only Cocoapod sourced libraries that include x86_64 are used in the target app. However, it's a problem when using libraries from other sources where there is no roll back option to x86_64 simulators (e.g. Swift Package Manager).

Is there a way to use lipo to generate `ios-arm64-simulator` from the two existing framework builds? Or is this something where `ios-arm64-simulator` needs to be built as another configuration from the HERE SDK source?

Comment: Try migrating to the Navigate Edition, it supports M1 out of the box: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/dev_guide/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you that we have already located this situation in the SDK and our team in charge of the SDK is working very hard to provide a solution to this problem in the next release of HERE SDK Premium.

Comment: Any updates? Can you recompile NMAKit xcframework to support m1 macs?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6hTbWv_1w8